# Is there an algorithm for calculating the multiplicative order of x modulo y (for y > 1000 execpt mod(x,y).multipliative_order())?

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate multiplicative order to solve a discrete logarithm problem. I've tried to use this algorithm below but it doesn't work with big numbers.

```
def multiplicativeOrder(A, N) : 
    if (GCD(A, N ) != 1) : 
        return -1

    result = 1

    K = 1
    while (K < N) : 

        result = (result * A) % N  

        if (result == 1) : 
            return K 

        K = K + 1

    return -1
```

Comment: Why don't they work with big numbers?  Takes too long, or it gives wrong answer?

Comment: The next best thing to try is the baby-step giant-step method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step

Comment: In general the discrete logarithm problem is very hard with no known algorithms. That's why crypto systems are based on it.

Comment: If you know the prime factors of phi(N) you could also test powers of A to a factor (also non-prime ones) of phi(N). Only those can be multiplicative orders.

Comment: An even stronger assertion than @Henry mentions is that the multiplicative order will divide λ(n), where lambda is the carmichael function.

Comment: @KevinWang Wang I think that they takes too long because I don't have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are faster ways of doing this, based on factorizing `n` and then applying a lot of math. However, as just a baseline improvement that goes from `O(n)` to `O(sqrt(n))` using the baby-step giant-step idea. Its also fairly simple compared to the alternative.

```python
def multiplicative_order2(a, n):
    if gcd(a, n) != 1:
        return -1

    visited = {}
    count = 0

    count = slow = fast = 1
    while fast not in visited:
        visited[slow] = count
        count += 1
        slow = (slow * a) % n
        fast = (fast * slow) % n

    return count * (count + 1) // 2 - visited[fast]
```

Comment: I tried this algorithm and still I can't find result. I have numbers like a = 702227857201910502803263771941068037519817288610097245394347621941015728230487046144424144943231650503866772475809523692408711744381600223736047502028508915319792853354544804460483510832833079502679789 and n = 101112291727540776972985120767760719674033925180426159196076506976941069135031638483497458157233007832240109931475852069446288391011301583654878123893316949064625850427289121786017761585395084880453019. Maybe you know any algorithms for that big numbers?

Comment: @Piotrek Get the prime factorization of `n`, compute the carmichael function of `n` using that, factorize *that*, and test only the factors (not necessarily prime). [Here is an implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order#Python) on rosetta stone. I haven't tested it, so I don't know how well it performs, but it should be asymptotically faster.

Comment: I notice your `n` has a factor of `41`, it may decompose into other small primes as well. If not, replace the sieve in that code with a pollard rho factorization implementation, and see if that outperforms it.

Comment: As an update, been running a pollard rho test for about 4-5 minutes now, with the only factor coming out to be 41. A miller rabin test proves that `n/41` is not prime however, so you've got some large primes in there somewhere.

Comment: If somebody wants to experiment more, the prime factors of this n are: 41, 5156375944943411590386538361, 478272624630427704478214021282257653202860708426195901985461900466499246717197403685747927136383533903581894079674250033267593213650786672414508598999823498833099917629819

Comment: @Henry how did you factorise it?

Comment: @גלעדברקן GP/PARI found them in a few minutes.

Comment: For the record, I followed up on @Henry 's calculations. with lambda(n) being: 1233076728384643621621769765221360269075443771912431516140291990190533903531190323196262441928128520937012394882441305571397115865420047882783339908894458869572482888515781192873307993333692468409240
The order is either that value, or 139222150513472112940436535720 times a factor of 8856900456119031564411370764486252837090013119003627814545590749379615679948100068254591243266361738955220260734708333949399874326866419859527937018515249978390739215367. GP/PARI found no factors (ran 1hour), but tests say its not prime